# Chord Diagram Software?

Tags: data-visualization

DO you know any kind of software that allows me to perform chord diagrams based on pairs ? For those who might not know I think that google images under 'chord diagrams' gives a clear idea. I'm asking because I haven't found anything on the programms that I use (SPSS, JMP, R etc.)

[image]

Comment: Which OS and what programming language are you targeting? Which price is acceptable? What are your license requirements; are viral open source licenses such as GPL ok?

Comment: [QACube](http://www.qacube.com/) has such a diagram and AFAIK they use a free JavaScript library. I think it was [D3](https://d3js.org/): For an example, see http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062006

Answer (score 1):

[Circos](http://circos.ca/) might be an option for this - it's designed for genetic data but apparently you can use any dataset if you massage it enough. I'm just getting to grips with it myself so it might not cover your situation though.

Alternatively, [Data Viz Catalogue](http://www.datavizcatalogue.com/methods/chord_diagram.html) mentions the [Circlize](http://www.r-graph-gallery.com/123-circular-plot-circlize-package-2/) package for R.